# JOptionPane won't Work: Aim use the Default option (customize the answer buttons)

Tags: java, joptionpane

This is the  Text, it won't work I allready checked it with the You AI

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Test_showConfirmDialog1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
        int Tester = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you smoke?", "",                    
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tester = " + Tester);
    }
```

Eclipse says: show.ConfirmDialog doesn't work. why? (I am a Beginner, I don't know most of Java but the code simply corrected woould be allready helpfull, I am sure I will figure out the rest by myself.)

Comment: The `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()` does **not** contain 8 parameters. Use the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` instead.

Comment: On a side: There is already a Constant for Yes/No buttons (`JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`). Be a little more inventive like: `Object[] options = {"Let's Do It", "Heck No"};`. Also, for the last parameter, the **initialValue** parameter, it should be `options[1].toString()` because it is of an **Object** type array. If it was a **String** type array, you wouldn't need the `.toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use `showConfirmDialog`, instead of using `showOptionDialog`.

Here is the code that is using the `showOptionDialog`:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
        int tester = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Do you smoke?", "",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                null, options, options[0]);
        // The variable 'tester' contains the index of the selected button
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tester = " + tester);
        // If you want to view directly the selected option (Yes or No):
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: " + options[tester]);
    }
    
}
```

If you only want to use Yes or No options, Java swing has a built-in dialog for that (it uses `showConfirmDialog`):

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tester = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you smoke?", "",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        // Yes = 0; No = 1; (clicking the close icon) = -1
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tester = " + tester);
    }
    
}
```

I hope it helped.